# Как запустить стороннюю программу из своей программы?

Tags: macos, java

Если мне надо запустить программу из консоли, которая находиться в папки с названием из двух частей(с пробелом в названии),  то делаю это так:

```
 $ open /"My project"/myprogram.app
```

то есть такую папку необходимо брать в кавычки.
Но как теперь сделать это из программу Java? Если попробовать так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /\"Meine Projekt\"/myprogram.app");
```

то ничего не происходит - myprogram.app не запускается. А вот такой код:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Projekt/myprogram.app");
```

будет работать.

Comment: вводите \"

Comment: Тогда нет никакого результата - myprogram.app не загрузился.

Comment: попробуйте так:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Meine\ Projekt/myprogram.app");

Comment: Здесь ошибка на уровне компиляции - неправильно составлена строка.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", "/Meine Projekt/myprogram.app" } );
```

С параметрами:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", "/Meine Projekt/myprogram.app", "--args", "param" } );
```

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: На JavaRanch пишут нужно все ковычки поубирать. Я обновил, попробуй.

Comment: Заработало. Но теперь пытаюсь запустить с параметрами: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", "/Meine Projekt/myprogram.app --args param" } );` и снова никакой реакции.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно указать переход в данную папку,откуда идет запуск программы... Для этого, например, в виндовс нужно собрать bat-file

```
cd <имя папки, где находится запускаемая программа>
patch = %PATCH%; <указать все необходимые пути для выполнения программы>
<путь к запускаемой на выполнение прграммы>
```

Затем

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec...<"имя Bat-file>
```

В UNIX аналогично собрать файл скриптов.